# SQL selection based upon status

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I have the above table and want to select those IDs that have the status ok. Is there a simple way to achieve that.

In the above table only ID=2 should be selected because only ID=2 has been mentioned twice with status OK. ID=1 has a 'OK' status and once 'X' status hence it should not be selected.

Comment: This question is about basic SQL competency - if  you know nothing about SQL, start by reading a tutorial.
You use SQL to query a database, the most basic query is : select * from [table] , whih selects all rows and columns from table. To filter the result use a WHERE clause.

Comment: @user172283 You should edit that additional requirement into your question instead of posting it as a comment.  That changes the solution quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some information about your data you have not shared, such as are there always 2 rows per Id, can there be a single row, more than 2?

Given you want to select just the `Id`, one simple solution is to use `group by` with a `having` clause and filter only Ids where the total number of Id values matches the number with a status of `OK`.

```
select id
from #X
group by id
having Count(*)=Sum(case when status='ok' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID from table where status = 'OK'
```

Use DISTINCT if you only want unique IDs

Answer (score 0):

The below will work.

```
   select distinct ID from table where status = 'OK' and ID not in (Select ID from table where 
   status <> 'OK')
```